# Jwplayer fails to run on DotNetNuke

Tags: jquery, asp.net, video, dotnetnuke, jwplayer

i have tried to implement a jwplayer as

```
<script src="js/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

<script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
               var divid= document.getElementById("mediaplayerid").getAttribute("id");
               alert(divid);
               jwplayer(divid).setup({
                    flashplayer: '<%= ResolveUrl("Jwplayer/player.swf")%>',
                    provider: "video",
                    file: '<%= ResolveUrl("Videos/2.mp4") %>' ,
                    autostart: true,
                    width: '600',
                    height:'370',
                    });
               });

</script>
```

where i have taken a div tag in a table as

```
       <div id="mediaplayerid"></div>
    </td>
```

the jwplayer fails to run. i have debug the script.It reaches to a point Jwplayer.setup after it that comes out with no output. what possibly be an error or any code error. thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Why don't you just write `jwplayer("mediaplayerid").setup({`? The first two rows seem redundant. Also, you've got this line twice: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Sir Problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is either that you haven't referenced the jQuery or the jwplayer in a correct way, or that the path to the video file/flashplayer is wrong. If you can debug your rendered code in Firebug, or something similar, you could check that all paths are valid.

I've copied your code and it seems to be working fine: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nF7Mw/120/)

You could also try changing the `ResolveUrl` to this, specifying the location of the video from the root of your project (or whatever the path is):

```
<%# ResolveUrl("/~Videos/2.mp4") %>
```

**EDIT**
I assume you have your jQuery reference in your code, even though you didn't paste it?

```
<script src="JavaScripts/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// var divid= document.getElementById("mediaplayerid").getAttribute("id");
// alert(divid);
jwplayer("mediaplayerid").setup({
flashplayer: '/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-VC_ManageLessions/Jwplayer/player.swf',
provider: "video",
file: '/DesktopModules/DNNCentric-VC_ManageLessions/Videos/2.mp4' ,
autostart: true,
width: '600',
height:'370',
});
});
</script>

Comment: Sir this is how it looks at firebug debugger.

Comment: Looks ok. Have you tried with another video, with another file type (e.g flv)? Just to check that it's not the video that is unplayable.

Comment: No sir even flv doesn't play. debugger reach to a Jwplayer after that it just fail to run the code.